# Find chart by title (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple charts on the page and need to get access to data from one of them.

What is the easiest way to find a chart by title? Are there any built-in helpers in Highcharts for this, or do I have to write my own lookup with something like:

```
function getChartByTitle(titleString) {
    var allCharts = Highcharts.charts;

    // 1. for each chart, get options
    // 2. look up the "title" attribute in the options 
    // 3. if matches `titleString`, return current chart
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function getChartByTitle(titleString) {
    var allCharts = Highcharts.charts;
    return allCharts.find(function(chart) {
        return chart.options && chart.options.title === titleString;
    });
}
```

Note: Array.prototype.find() is not supported in all browsers (if you use it check compatibility).

Currently supported solution would be using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function getChartByTitle(titleString) {
    var allCharts = Highcharts.charts;
    var result = allCharts.filter(function(chart) {
        return chart.options && chart.options.title === titleString;
    });
    return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Can't use ES2015 yet (need IE10 support), but I do have lodash available, so could use that as an alternative.

Comment: @mikhail then use the second solution

Comment: The answer I posted worked for me, but your answer is more universal, so I'm picking this one.

Answer (score 3):

Since I have `lodash` available, if nobody suggests anything built-in for Highcharts, I will end up using this:

```
function getChartByTitle(titleString) {
    var allCharts = Highcharts.charts,
        searchTarget = {options: {title: {text: titleString}}};

    return _.find(allCharts, searchTarget);
};
```